# Sass source maps with minified file (grunt)

Tags: sass, gruntjs, minify, source-maps

Using Sass with sourcemaps works fine for me with unminified CSS, but using my minified CSS it doesn't.
I'm guessing this might be because the references first get's built to the compiled css file, but then the minified version changes everything and references then fail, could that be it? If so, I still don't know what to do about it. Any help to find a solution would be much appreciated.

This is in my last line of my main *scss-file:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=mytheme-full.css.map */
```

I'm thinking; If I just change to the following, it should work. But no!

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=mytheme-full-min.css.map */
```

This is from my Gruntfile.js:

```
    cssmin: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/mytheme-full-min.css': 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/mytheme-full.css'
            }
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sourcemap: 'auto'
            },
            files: {
                'sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/mytheme-full.css': 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/sass/mytheme-full.scss'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I have the same issue here. Did you ever manage to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

To date, grunt-contrib-cssmin doesn't support sourcemaps (see [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/issues/58) and [here](https://github.com/tollwerk/generator-tollwerk/issues/15#issuecomment-64985597)).

However, both grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-autoprefixer support sourcemaps, so your best bet is probably to enable sourcemaps on those and use the unminified css for development and debugging. To enable sourcemaps in autoprefixer, just set:

```
options: {
  map: true
}
```